# Может ли компилятор инлайнить функции, реализация которой вынесена в cpp файл?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, inline

Может ли компилятор инлайнить функции, реализация которой вынесена в cpp файл? Функции и методы реализованные в месте объявления по умолчанию являются inline, и встраиваются на усмотрение компилятора, но ограничивает ли компилятор то, что реализация вынесена в cpp файл?

Comment: Если он видит код в точке вызова, то может. (из вашего описания не понятно, вызов функции происходит из текста в том же файле, где  расположен ее код или из другого)

Comment: Да, компилятор может инлайнить любые функции, определение которых ему доступно, независимо от размещения (т.е. вызов и определение могут находится в разных единицах трансляции).

Comment: @avp ,  из другого файла

Comment: Тогда "обычный" компайлер (из знакомых мне) не сможет

Comment: @avp ¿Вы что, эксклюзивно turbo C++ пользуетесь?

Comment: Зависит от компилятора... Посмотрите, например, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ltcg-link-time-code-generation?view=msvc-170

Comment: @user7860670, если вправду интересно, то GCC и MetaWare (в зависимости от чипа)

Comment: @avp GCC же умеет в кросс-единицетрансляционную оптимизацию `-flto`

Comment: @user7860670, нам важно, чтобы все было максимально предсказуемо. Чем меньше компайлер "думает", тем лучше. Проще понять, "где собака порылась", если при тестировании чипа что-то идет не так, как задумывалось дизайнерами. (но, вообще, спасибо, учту на будущее такую фичу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Только если функция вызывается из того же файла, или если включена оптимизация во время линковки (`-flto` на GCC и Clang-е, указывать и при компиляции, и при линковке).

> Функции и методы реализованные в месте объявления по умолчанию являются inline,

Только если они определены внутри тела класса.